# How do I list all users in a view that have created a node with certain taxonomy terms?

Tags: 8, views, taxonomy-terms, search

The goal is to create a view to list users on a page with url /search/[category]/[topic]/[location] where "category" "topic" and "location" are taxonomy fields in nodes that users can create.

I want to list all users that have a node were the "search" queries apply.

***/search/all/all/all*** should list all users

***/search/all/topic1/all*** should list all users that created at least one node with topic "topic1".

***/search/category1/topic2/location3*** should list all users that have created at least one node with taxonomy terms "category1", "topic2" and "location3".

Edit: I have machine names for my taxonomy terms and that is how I would like to use in the url.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making a relationship between the user and nodes. then I added each taxonomy term as a relationship through the nodes. Then I added 3 contextual filters for each taxonomy term. Finally I switched on aggregation and aggregated the usernames.